# How to see details about user, even if they're not registered?

Tags: freeswitch

I'm currently using FreeSwitch in my workstation. How do i see details about a single user, even if they're not registered, like the 'sip show peer' command in Asterisk that shows last known IP, user agent, etc ? Is it possible to do that in FreeSwitch or it does'nt have that function ?

I already tried the answers here regarding the commands that list all users ( list_users and sofia status profile default reg ) and it only shows info of registered users. I need to check that same kind of info but for not registered users like in Asterisk with 'sip show peer'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get data from user directory by executing fs_cli commands:

> **find_user_xml**
>
> Checks to see if a user exists. Matches user tags found in the directory, similar to user_exists, but returns an XML representation of the user as defined in the directory (like the one shown in user_exists).
>
> Usage: `find_user_xml <key> <user> <domain>`
>
> `<key>` references a key specified in a directory's user tag
>
> `<user>` represents the value of the key
>
> `<domain>` is the domain to which the user is assigned.

or

> **list_users**
>
> Lists Users configured in Directory
>
> Usage:
>
> `list_users [group <group>] [domain <domain>] [user <user>] [context <context>]`
>
> Examples:
>
> `freeswitch@localhost> list_users group default`
>
> userid|context|domain|group|contact|callgroup|effective_caller_id_name|effective_caller_id_number
>   2000|default|192.168.20.73|default|sofia/internal/sip:2000@192.168.20.1:5060|tech|Test|2000
>   2001|default|192.168.20.73|default|sofia/internal/sip:2001@192.168.20.1:63412;rinstance=8e2c8b86809acf2a|tech|Test|2001

or

> **user_data**
>
> Retrieves user information (parameters or variables) as defined in the FreeSWITCH user directory.
>
> Usage:
>
> `user_data <user>@<domain> <attr|var|param> <name>`
>
> `<user>` is the user's id
>
> `<domain>` is the user's domain
>
> `<attr|var|param>` specifies whether the requested data is contained in
>   the "variables" or "parameters" section of the user's record
>
> `<name>` is the name (key) of the variable to retrieve
>
> Examples:
>
> `user_data 1000@192.168.1.101 param password`
>
> will return a result of 1234, and
>
> `user_data 1000@192.168.1.101 var accountcode`
>
> will return a result of 1000 from the example user shown in user_exists, and
>
> `user_data 1000@192.168.1.101 attr id`
>
> will return the user's actual alphanumeric ID (i.e. "john") when number-alias="1000" was set as an attribute for that user.

You can get more info here:

[ https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_commands ]

Comment: Hi. Thank you, just did it here and it worked like i was expected!